# Getting AD info using Get-ADGroupMember not working as expected

Tags: powershell

So i am trying to write a script that basically gets a list of AD groups, and then with each group, gets the members and memberof.

So far i have this :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    $groupList = get-adgroup -filter *| select-object Name | sort-object -property name
```

Which works fine. nice and simple. No problem. When i run `write-output $groupList`, it spits out the list of my AD groups. Happy days!

Then I add this :

```
foreach($group in $groupList){

    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group
```

So my code block looks like this :

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$groupList = get-adgroup -filter *| select-object Name | sort-object -property name

foreach($group in $groupList){

    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group
}
```

And get this error :

```
Get-ADGroupMember : Cannot bind parameter 'Identity'. Cannot create object of type 
"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup". The adapter cannot set the value of property "Name".
```

I have also tried this :

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties MemberOf | Where-Object {$_.MemberOf -ne $null} | Select-Object Name,MemberOf
```

Which works great in Powershell:

[Image of working script results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJzkb.jpg)

Yet strangley, when i then add the `export-csv` on the end, that same error returns :

[Exported-CSV image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6gXX.png)

Can someone please educate me, as no doubt its myself being a little stoopid.

Thanks.

Comment: Remove `| select-object Name` from the first pipeline so it just says `$groupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Sort-Object -Property Name`

Comment: yes, either removing the `| select-object Name` or make `$groupList = (get-adgroup -filter *| select-object Name | sort-object -property name).Name`

Comment: Member and MemberOf will show _ADValueCollection_ when exported to CSV unless you convert them to _string_ loop over and put each member on a single row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$groupList` does not directly contain an array of strings / names. 
Use the following command to get only the names:

```
$groupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

---

`MemberOf` and `Members`  are arrays. `Export-Csv` does not know how to export them into a file. Here an example, how to handle this.

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties MemberOf, Members | `
    Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = 'MemberOf'; Expression = {$_.MemberOf -join ';'}}, @{Name = 'Members'; Expression = {$_.Members -join ';'}} | `
    Export-Csv -Path 'path' -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks guys that helped a little.

So now i have refined my code to a single line :

`Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties MemberOf,Members`

Which spits out what I need. However adding the export.... 
`| export-csv C:\Users\UserName\desktop\exportattmpt.csv`

 makes it go wrong again. The output places "`Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection`" in the member and memberof columns??

Comment: What data (row headers) would you like to export into the csv? Does `Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties MemberOf,Members | Sort-Object -Property MemberOf, Members | export-csv C:\Users\UserName\desktop\exportattmpt.csv` work?

Comment: So essentially, i am looking to get a big list of ALL groups, and then get for each group, members, and memberof. This needs to then be exported in CSV format, which in turn will get plugged into Draw.IO to auto generate a diagram. I will test that and let you know.

Comment: So that does work, in a way. So the MEMBER and MEMBEROF column shows 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection' instead of the actual group name.

Comment: Could you upload your latest code and also a example row of the expected CSV file so I could take a look.

Comment: This is what i get : https://pasteboard.co/LxwP87rpq2EH.png

Comment: Latest code: `Get-ADGroup -filter * -Properties MemberOf,Members | export-csv.......`

This produces exactly what i need, except it dosent fill the member/member of columns as per the pasteboard image above.

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: You sir are a Diamond!! That's perfect! thanks for that! I got what i needed, and i will also take the code and learn from it. Thanks. Ping me an email and ill throw you a beer token or something!